# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/location/places/zzl.class

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-places-api, android-studio-2.3

I am having this problem when i run my project in my device, note that this Error does not show up during gradle sync, but only when i run project.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/location/places/zzl.class

this my app/build gradle:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "il.co.dotech.constinspect"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {

compile 'com.schibstedspain.android:leku:2.3.1'

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
//compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0'

compile'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'

compile 'com.github.medyo:fancybuttons:1.8.2'
compile 'com.github.Mariovc:ImagePicker:1.0.4'
compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'

compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.2'
compile 'org.json:json:20160212'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1.1@aar'
compile'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'

compile 'com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:2.0.3'
compile 'com.mikepenz:actionitembadge:3.3.1@aar'
compile 'com.mikepenz:iconics-core:2.8.1@aar'
compile 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:4.7.0.0@aar'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile files('libs/gson-1.7.1.jar')



androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and this is my build gradle:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this line in your `app/build gradle` dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.8.0'
```

Comment: adding this library realy solved the problem, thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it helped ;)